# Online - Audit reports with full URL for classic pages views

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing, web-analytics

I'm using SharePoint Online with some classic pages in the root site.

So I've some URLs like https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Items.aspx?itemId=xx

I would like to know which users are viewing this page, but I would also know which `itemId` they are requesting.

I've checked the audit report area in Office 365 admin center, and I found this data, but I can not see the entire URL and it is always like https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Items.aspx.

Is there a way to see the full URL? I don't want to set up a Google Analytics account only for this purpose, so I hope there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, it will be not doable for audit log to get the parameters like the Item ID. As I am not sure about your final goal, the only thing i can suggest is to use the filters in audit log search to have the results your want. Like access event to certain file